# Drawing a bounding box around objects within a threshold in Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV for this particular task. I have an image and I am trying to identify and remove all objects that have an aspect ratio higher than 3:1. But for some reason, I am unable to draw the bounding boxes around them at all. This is the code that I have so far:

```
import cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



img = cv2.imread('Shapes-blurred.png', 0)
ret, binary_img = cv2.threshold(img, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if int(rect[3]/rect[2]) < 3: continue
    x,y,w,h = rect
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow("Show",img)
cv2.waitKey()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi @atomheartmommy put your input image to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the height of the bounding rectangle is larger than the width. That may or may not be the case. Also, the bounding rectangle is always parallel to the x and y axis, and that might not match your contour shape. To get the true elongation factor of a contour I would recommend using cv2.minAreaRect(contour). That function returns the rectangle mass center, width and height, and angle.
Using the width and height from this function, you can calculate the elongation factor as:

```
(x, y), (w, h), angle = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
elongation_factor = max(w, h)/min(w, h)
```